# Create wi-fi hotspot using specific network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I have an Ubuntu box. It has both an internal and external (USB) wi-fi adapter. I can connect to wi-fi networks on either.

However, I need to set up a hotspot using this machine. It has to use the second, external adapter.

```
hardwaresyseng@hw-ble-station:~/dan_rsync$ nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
enx00e04c681267  ethernet  connected     Profile 1  
wlo1             wifi      disconnected  --         
wlx9418655b6ec2  wifi      disconnected  --         
p2p-dev-wlo1     wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
eno2             ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
```

wlo1 is the built-in, wlx94... is the external.

When I try to use the wi-fi GUI, creating a hotspot always defaults to using the base device (Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi) rather than the external (NetGear Wi-Fi).

How can I resolve this?

Ideally, I can choose to enable the hotspot using a command rather than a GUI element.